# ASP.net IdentiyServer 3 AuthorizationCodeReceived not firing

Tags: asp.net, openid, identityserver3

when a user authenticates with Identity Server 3, AuthorizationCodeReceived never fires.  RedirectToIdentityProvider  does get fired but thats it.  I am trying to call a function that will get the users email or windows ID, and then add a custom claim.  But without the AuthorizationCodeReceived method being called, I am not sure how to do that.  Anyone have experience with this?  Not sure if it matters, but my code is ASP.net windows form (not MVC)

Here is my code:

```
    Public Sub ConfigureAuth(app As IAppBuilder)
        ServicePointManager.SecurityProtocol = SecurityProtocolType.Tls12
        JwtSecurityTokenHandler.DefaultInboundClaimTypeMap = New Dictionary(Of String, String)


        app.UseCookieAuthentication(New CookieAuthenticationOptions() With {
            .AuthenticationType = CookieAuthenticationDefaults.AuthenticationType
        })

        Dim OpenIdAuthOption = New OpenIdConnectAuthenticationOptions() With {
           .Authority = "https://myidentityserver.azurewebsites.net/core/",
           .ClientId = "adfafasfasdfa",
           .RedirectUri = "https://localhost:44321/default.aspx/",
           .ResponseType = ("access_token"),
           .RequireHttpsMetadata = False,
           .SignInAsAuthenticationType = "Cookies",
           .Notifications = New OpenIdConnectAuthenticationNotifications() With {

                .AuthorizationCodeReceived = Function(ctx)
                                                 Dim claimPrincipal As ClaimsPrincipal = ctx.AuthenticationTicket.Identity.Claims
                                                 TransformClaims(claimPrincipal)
                                                 Return Task.FromResult(0)
                                             End Function,
                .RedirectToIdentityProvider = Function(context)
                                                  RedirectLogin(context)
                                                  Return Task.FromResult(0)
                                              End Function
                }
        }
        app.UseOpenIdConnectAuthentication(OpenIdAuthOption)
    End Sub
```